# Maximum overlap of two rectangles of given shape

Tags: geometry, optimization

[Problem] For two rectangles of given shape in a plane, what is their maximum overlap?

There are many possible cases:
It's obvious that when one of the rectangles can cover the other, the maximum will be the area of the smaller rectangle. The first case (picture 1) is quite easy to deal with using pure geometry as well, but when the overlap is like the second picture, it's quite hard to deal with.

Many of the solutions I've seen are approximations or algorithms. I'd be very grateful if anyone could provide a pure mathematical proof, using geometry or algebra.
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In5vK.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT6nL.png)

Comment: In both configuration given in question one can increase overlapping area by shift of one of the rectangles up-down or left-right. The only position when such shift cannot increase overlapping area is position with symmetric overlapping, when centers of rectangles coincide. I believe there is no simple formula for maximum overlapping area for given sizes of rectangles but using the fact that rectangles have common centers leaves only one variable: angle of rotation, so one can find maximum with varying this angle.

Comment: Yes, I can prove that the two rectangles have common centers, but there are quite a lot of possible cases of overlapping, so the algebra may be hard.